# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

За счет того, что диск и вал в этой серии затвора выполнены как одна деталь, достигается большая надежность конструкции затвора, а механическая фиксация покрытия на диске позволяет исключить его отслаивание от диска.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна. Оборот "как" тесно связан со сказуемом и не имеет значения сравнения.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, запятая не нужна.